# Best way to attach an arbitrary callback function to a dom element?

Tags: javascript

The following (vanillajs) code works fine

```
// library code:
let close_cb;   // nasty global var...

...
    let tree = document.createElement('ul');
    tree.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        ...
//      let close_cb = tree.getAttribute('CLOSE_CB');
//      let close_cb = tree.onchange;
        close_cb(leaf.id, ', so there');

// user code:
    function my_close_cb(id, msg) {
        const footer = document.querySelector('footer');
        footer.innerHTML = id + ' is closed' + msg;
    }   
//  tree.setAttribute('CLOSE_CB',my_close_cb);
//  tree.onchange = my_close_cb;
    close_cb = my_close_cb;
```

However the commented-out s/getAttribute code fails, getAttribute puts full text of "function my_close_cb(..." in local close_cb.

The commented-out onchange hack actually works, but feels terribly dodgy to say the least, although it is certainly closer to what I'm after.

Note the "library code" is hand written and fully under my control, whereas "user code" is intended to be transpiled or otherwise machine-generated, so changing my_close_cb to accept a single event argument would be a complete non-starter.

What is the best way to attach an arbitrary callback function that accepts an arbitrary set of parameters to a dom element?

Comment: Can you edit your question and turn your code into a runnable snippet. I don't really understand the question. The commented code is confusing as it has two consecutive assignments to the same variable. Evidently, the second of those two assigns a function reference, while the first is a string. It would really help if we can *run* code to see an illustration of the problem. I don't get what the role of the attribute is in all this.

Comment: `tree.<some name> = my_close_cb` is totally fine. Alternatively you could `addEventListener` to a custom event.

Comment: @Jonas Oh my, so it is. I just automatically assumed it would go "no such field". Ho hum, happy new year, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tree.close_cb` or any other property to store a function or anything else is totally fine, as the DOM is just a (persistent) tree of JavaScript objects. As such they behave like any other JS object, and properties can be added without any restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a plain json property to the DOM element.

```
document.body.callback = function cb(text) { console.log(text); };
document.body.callback("hello world");
```